# Objective C: Displaying Array Elements

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, xcode

As far as my study is concern for Objective C, I found this code for displaying the array elements:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c"];
int x = 0;

for(; x<[myArray count]; x++)
    NSLog(@"value at index %i is %@", x, [myArray objectAtIndex:x]);
```

I am just curious if this is possible below: using `[myArray[x]]` instead of `[myArray objectAtIndex:x]` instead

```
for(; x < [myArray count]; x++)
    NSLog(@"value at index %i is %@", x, [myArray[x]]);
```

Comment: By the way, my book might help you: much of the emphasis of its early chapters is on Objective-C, the language. Here's the chapter on syntax: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. An NSArray is not a C array; it's an object like any other object and you have to talk to it the way you'd talk to any other object, using full-fledged message syntax. (The only "shortcut" of the sort you're looking for is properties.) I'm sorry, but Objective-C is horribly verbose, and this is an excellent case in point. You'll become accustomed to using code completion as much as possible, to avoid typing all those letters...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, and the reason is fairly simple: Objective-C is based on C and retains backwards compatibility.

In C, using `[i]` on an object will call the `[]` operator of that object. However, on the local scope all Objective-C objects are simply pointers, which would make the call something similar to `int[3]`. Does that look valid to you?

Implementing `[]` for `NSArray` would mean breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: I believe Objective-C is based on C, not on C++ (but the point is probably the same).

Comment: Hey, that's interesting. I've been programming heavily in Objective-C for almost two years now, and I never realized it's based on C. It mixes really well with C++ :-) Updated my answer.

Comment: That's because C++ is very nearly a superset of C, which makes Objective-C look like it could be an extension of a subset of C++.  But in fact, it was based on C, and was developed around the same time that C++ was.  The add-on stuff is based on Smalltalk.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt - Objective-C++ is actually a different language. That may be what you've been using...

Comment: @matt I highly doubt that, since I've simply been using the standard iOS Objective-C.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt cool - I'm just saying that if you really love C++ and want the benefits of using it, you can: there is a standard iOS Objective-C++. Change the source file suffix from _.m_ to _.mm_ and presto, you're there. And ARC continues to work.